# Button Visible like relay

Tags: vb.net

hi can you help me how to put 6 button in in a vb form but 1 private sub or whatever you need and make it hide and show each other when you move your mouse on it it is possible ? example when i point my mouse on button 1 the button 2 appear then when i  point on button 2 the 3rd button appear and so on the other buttons

im new at vb.net 
    Public Class Form1

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseMove,
    Button2.MouseMove, Button3.MouseMove, Button4.MouseMove, Button5.MouseMove, Button6.MouseMove

        Button1.Hide()
        Button2.Show()
        Button2.Hide()
        Button3.Show()
        Button3.Hide()
        Button4.Show()
        Button4.Hide()
        Button5.Show()
        Button5.Hide()
        Button6.Show()
        Button6.Hide()
        Button1.Show()


    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You cant (shouldn't) wire MouseMove events to a Click event - they have different signatures.

Comment: So every time the mouse moves at all you want to immediately show and re-hide every button?  That doesn't seem like it would accomplish much.

Comment: This sounds like a homework project since there'd be no practical reason to do this. So I won't give you an answer, but I will give you tips. You are using the wrong event. What you do is subscribe to the `MouseMove` event of `Button1`, and put `Button2.Show()` inside there. Then subscribe to the `MouseMove` event of `Button2` and do the same thing and so on.

Comment: can you help me sir. i don't know what to do right now my brain is blowing up i don't even think its possible but my prof said you can do it but how? he make's us all down but trial and error i just want some tips or maybe method to make it possible

Comment: @MacapagalGalvezEmmanuel: Take a look at events like MouseEnter and MouseLeave for individual controls: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter  You can perform actions when a mouse hovers over a particular control.  Instead of... whatever it is you're doing now.

Comment: thank you sir it helps a lot now i understand

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the form load

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Button1.Show()
        Button2.Hide()
        Button3.Hide()
        Button4.Hide()
        Button5.Hide()
        Button6.Hide()
    End Sub
```

Then handle button mouse move event in one function call for all buttons as shown below. and write logic as shown below.

I wrote it for 3 buttons. You can plan for rest.

**SCROLL below code to left see all button mouse move events handled.**

```
Private Sub Button_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As    System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseMove, Button2.MouseMove, Button3.MouseMove, Button4.MouseMove, Button5.MouseMove, Button6.MouseMove
        If (Button1.Visible) Then
            Button1.Hide()
            Button2.Show()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If (Button2.Visible) Then
            Button2.Hide()
            Button3.Show()
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank God it works.. thanks @Pavan Chandaka it works now i can make some color for each button thank you men your answer is awsome

Comment: if everything works fine accept it as answer, so that others can reuse the logic for relay display.

Comment: btw can i possible make it shortcut i mean make it only a few lines so i can have a better view for each code do that possible?

Comment: I guess you are asking to reduce the size of the function and make it more readable.

Comment: yes sir that's what i mean :D can you make it 2 functional line for all 6 button?

Comment: Will give a try

Comment: you can iterate all controls. But that will become a costly operation.   "For I As Integer = 0 To Controls.Count
            If ((TypeOf Controls(I) Is System.Windows.Forms.Button)) Then"    Then you can hadle your logic.